# Why does Conv2D seems to only performing in 1D?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I trying to understand how Tensorflow work.
I have this code going trying to perform 2D convolution on an input image of size (5,5).
But it seems that it is only performing convolution in 1D instead of 2D.

Here is the code:

```
iX = iY = 5
kX = kY = 3
image = np.ones((iY,iX)).reshape((iY,iX,1))
kernel = np.ones((kY,kX)).reshape((kY,kX,1,1))
bias = np.array([0.0])
i = layers.Input(shape=(iY,iX,1))#l_input
x = layers.Conv2D(1, (kY,kX), strides=1, padding="same", activation='linear',weights=[kernel,bias])(i)#l_conv2d(i)
model = keras.Model(i, x)

model(image).numpy()
```

Actual output:

```
[2, 3, 3, 3, 2]  
[2, 3, 3, 3, 2]  
[2, 3, 3, 3, 2]  
[2, 3, 3, 3, 2]  
[2, 3, 3, 3, 2]
```

Expected output:

```
[4, 6, 6, 6, 4]  
[6, 9, 9, 9, 6]  
[6, 9, 9, 9, 6]  
[6, 9, 9, 9, 6]  
[4, 6, 6, 6, 4]
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: what output you are expecting?

Comment: updated actual and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mentioned `padding='same'` that's why you are getting output having the same shape as the input image **5x5x1x1** it is in the format `Height X Width X Channel X No_of_filters`. `padding='same'` parameter add additional padding values to the image to get the desired output volume shape. you can use `padding='valid'` to avoid padding.

You have missed batch dimension as well while providing an image to the model:

```
iX = iY = 9
kX = kY = 3
no_of_filter = 2
image = np.ones((iY,iX)).reshape((1,iY,iX,1))
kernel = np.ones((kY,kX,no_of_filter)).reshape((kY,kX,1,no_of_filter))
bias = np.array([0.0 for _ in range(no_of_filter)])
i = layers.Input(shape=(iY,iX,1))#l_input
x = layers.Conv2D(no_of_filter, (kY,kX), strides=1, padding="valid", activation='linear',weights=[kernel,bias])(i) #l_conv2d(i)
model = keras.Model(i, x)
model.summary()
model(image).numpy().shape
```

Comment: Indeed looked like i missed the batch number when providing the image to the model, thanks!